# How to check which object my character is colliding with?

Tags: python, collision-detection

I am working on collision detection for a game, so that if the character runs into an object they stop moving.  As part of my solution for this, I have made two functions that iterate through a list of on screen objects to check for collision.

The first function (on_key_up) checks for collision when the direction key is held down and then stops character movement when True.

The second part of this is another function (on_key_up) that moves the character slightly out of the collision zone so he is free to move again.  This is triggered when releasing the direction key.

The problem is that I need to access the height and width attributes of whichever object the character is colliding with so I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

I posted a snippet of what I did so you can see the direction I'm trying to go in.

What did I do wrong here?

```
def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/faceleft.png'
                for i in listofwidgets:
                    if self.collide_widget(i):
                        self.x = ((listofwidgets(i).x + listofwidgets(i).width + .1)-self.x) + self.x
```

Comment: The widgets are the objects you are colliding with?

Comment: What are the properties of `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to simply change:

`self.x = ((listofwidgets(i).x + listofwidgets(i).width + .1)-self.x) + self.x`

to:

`self.x = (i.x + i.width + .1)-self.x) + self.x`

Also `listofwidgets(i)` would be a function call, it should probably be `listofwidgets[i]` (if it wasn't just a typo)

Answer (score 0):

`listofwidgets(i)` is the object you are colliding with, so either store that widget, or `i` in a variable for later use.